# Write a row query in Sqllite room

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to write this query by using sqllite room query with Dao Class. I.getItemID() is a dynamic variable.

```css
"SELECT item_quantity FROM item WHERE item_id ='"+I.getItemID()+"'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-params) for more information regarding accessing-data using room.

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {

    @Query("SELECT item_quantity FROM item WHERE item_id = :itemId")
    public int getItemQuantity(String itemId);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is what you meant, you almost got it then:

```
"SELECT item_quantity FROM item WHERE item_id = :I.getItemID()"
```